# Counter in jsp with external java file

Tags: java, html, jsp, package

I want to write a counter in jsp. This is my code:

Countinghilfe.java:

```
package Counting;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Countinghilfe{

public static int getCount(){
String s="";
try {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Anzahl.txt"));
s=in.readLine();


} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Integer zahl=new Integer(s);
return zahl;
}

public static void increase(){

String s="";
try {
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Anzahl.txt"));
s=in.readLine();
Integer zahl=new Integer(s);
zahl++;
BufferedWriter output=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Anzahl.txt"));
output.write(String.valueOf(zahl));
output.close();
 } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}   
 }
```

And in the counter.jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="Counting.Countinghilfe" %>
<%
Countinghilfe cl = new Countinghilfe();
out.println("<h2>Sie sind der ");
out.println( cl.getCount());
out.println(". Besucher auf unserer Site!</h2>");
cl.increase();
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The error shown is: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load  class for JSP.
and these:

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. Counting.Countinghilfe resolves to a package

Countinghilfe cannot be resolved to a type

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is the class Countinghilfe available in WEB-INF/classes/Counting folder?

Comment: no, i didn't really use any of these folders yet, because everything worked fine without it. i just had both files on my work server without any extra folders

Comment: Need more information on what server you are using? Development IDE you use?

Comment: the server is from my workplace, normal tomcat server. every employee has his /workgroup/name/.. directory where he can upload his own website